# How to count bookings made by people who signed up through an affiliate

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a hotel booking site. 
A user has to sign up before they make a booking. They can either sign up through an affiliate, or from the booking site directly.  The affiliates place signup url on their websites, when a user clicks on the link they are redirected to the sign up page of my booking site.

affiliates table

[image: affiliate table]

Below is my users table, aff_id means person1 and 4 signed up through affiliates with id’s 1 and 3. Null means person 2 and 3 din’t signup through an affiliate, they visited the sign up page directly.

user table

[image: user table]

Below is my booking table

[image: booking table]

Now I want to count all bookings that were made by people who signed up through affiliates

I know I have to use an asql join statement but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Did you look at the manual for how a `join` works? HTML and PHP are irrelevant here. You should tag the DB (mysql, mssql, etc.) you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Select count(b.Booking_Id)
    from booking b
    join user u on b.P_ID = u.P_ID
    where u.aff_ID is not null;
```

Comment: I did it like this Select count(b.bkg_id)
from booking b
join person u on b.bkg_ref_person = u.per_id
join affiliate a on a.aff_id = u.aff_id; and it worked. Thank you for the clue

Comment: You don't need the nested joins I have edited my answer with where condition and it will work. Please mark the answer as accepted if it clarifies.